# How to print powershell command from a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to print to file power-shell command.
The file in network directory.
This is my code:

```
@echo off

break> \\90.0.0.209\Britannica\backup\Maor_Tests \\90.0.0.209\Britannica\backup

echo 
wmic computersystem get PrimaryOwnerNAME, model >> \\90.0.0.209\Britannica\backup\Maor_Tests\Test.txt

wmic bios get serialnumber >> \\90.0.0.209\Britannica\backup\Maor_Tests\Test.txt

wmic cpu get name >> \\90.0.0.209\Britannica\backup\Maor_Tests\Test.txt 

systeminfo | findstr C:"OS Name" >> \\90.0.0.209\Britannica\backup\Maor_Tests\Test.txt

REM When I try to execute this command, I get gibbersh text only on that command.
PowerShell Get-PhysicalDisk | Format-Table -AutoSize | \\90.0.0.209\Britannica\backup\Maor_Tests\Test.txt     

@pause
```

How can I  print to file that command from this batch file?

Comment: is there a reason for mixing CMD, exe files, and powershell?

Comment: No, just need the info. And only with powershell command i succeed to acquire that info. If there any option to get that info with cmd command it will be better.

Comment: Why are you piping the result table? Is that how you're attempting to write it into your text file? Have you opened up a PowerShell window and tried `Get-PhysicalDisk | Format-Table -AutoSize | \\90.0.0.209\Britannica\backup\Maor_Tests\Test.txt` directly to make sure it works. BTW, every one of your commands can be improved upon, and I would recommend that you just do it all in PowerShell.

Comment: Every command works fine on my local pc. But in the network directory i get an error msg.

Comment: @MaorAzulay - what info do you need about the drives? the actual physical drives, the logical drives? what detail is needed? ///// i ask because the way that you are doing this is rather confusing. you can get almost all the info you want from `Get-ComputerInfo ` if you are running win10 with ps5.1 or higher.

Comment: I need only the specific details not all Get-ComputerInfo

Comment: @MaorAzulay - if you want to send a notice to someone when you comment, you need to add `@UserName` to the start of the comment. [*grin*]

Comment: @MaorAzulay - OK, but i can't test your powershell problem since that cmdlet is not available on win7ps5.1 because MS left it out. ///// my recommendation is to go with pure powershell since that is both easier to do AND easier to display neatly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the last line:

```
PowerShell Get-PhysicalDisk | Out-String | Add-Content '\\90.0.0.209\Britannica\backup\Maor_Tests\Test.txt'
```

The script is a bit of a mess though, like others have said why not do it all in PowerShell? Something like this will give you a much neater output (note that this is pure Powershell and can't be put as is in a CMD-file but should be in a .ps1):

```
$OutPutFile = '\\localhost\temp\test.txt'

$ComputerInfo = Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object BiosSeralNumber,CsModel,CsName,CsPrimaryOwnerName,CsProcessors,OsName
$PhysicalDisks = Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceId,FriendlyName,Size
$ComputerInfoObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Name'  =   $ComputerInfo.CsName
    'OS'    =   $ComputerInfo.OsName
    'Model' =   $ComputerInfo.CsModel
    'Owner' =   $ComputerInfo.CsPrimaryOwnerName
    'CPU'   =   $ComputerInfo.CsProcessors.Name
    'S/N'   =   $ComputerInfo.BiosSeralNumber
    }
foreach ($Disk in $PhysicalDisks) {
    $ComputerInfoObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Disk $($Disk.DeviceId)" -NotePropertyValue "$($Disk.FriendlyName), Size: $([int]($Disk.Size/1e9))GB"
}
$ComputerInfoObject | Out-String | Set-Content -LiteralPath $OutPutFile
```

What the resulting textfile looks like:

```
Name   : LABWORKSTATION
OS     : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Model  : All Series
Owner  : Microsoft
CPU    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4670K CPU @ 3.40GHz
S/N    : System Serial Number
Disk 0 : NVMe Samsung SSD 960, Size: 500GB
Disk 1 : Samsung SSD 840 EVO 500GB, Size: 500GB
```

Comment: @MaorAzulay You do understand that this needs to run in Powershell and not in cmd.exe right?

Comment: Exactly what "gibberish text" are you getting. Post some output so we can see what's happening.

Comment: Model                PrimaryOwnerName  
HP EliteBook 840 G5  ********       
SerialNumber  
XXXXXXXXX    
Name                                      
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8350U CPU @ 1.70GHz  
潈瑳丠浡㩥††††††††䜠䱏䑁ഴ伊⁓慎敭›†††††††††楍牣獯景⁴楗摮睯⁳〱䔠瑮牥牰獩൥.   The last line of powershell command @PMental